# Hodgkin-Huxley Model and Propagation of Action Potential

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology

I'm studying Hodgkin-Huxley model of action potential, and I have some confusion.

In the well-stated HH model, we have time constants for each ion currents, described as the reciprocal of the sum of forward rate and backward rate.

In the caple theory, there is another time constant that is defined as the multiple of cell resistance and cell capacitance.

Is there any relationship between the two time constants? Do we have to think the two processes, which means the 'generation' of action potential and the 'propagation' of it separately?

Thanks.